# Javascript split strings in array on specific index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of strings.

```
const numbersArray = ['1000','10000','100000']
```

My goal is to split each one of them on specific index for example: output of 1000 should be `1,000` and etc...

Here is what i have right now:

```
  const splitArrayHandler = (arr) =>{
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let indexOfSymbol = Math.round(arr[i].length / 3)
    return splitAtIndex(arr[i],indexOfSymbol)
  }
}

const splitAtIndex = (value,index) => {
  return value.substring(0,index) + ',' + value.substring(index)
}

splitArrayHandler(numbersArray)
```

The first function `splitArrayHandler` loops through my array,finds specific index of the symbol in the string and then function `splitAtIndex` does the rest of the hard work.

The problem is only first element of the string is passing to the `splitAtIndex`function and I dont understand why. any suggestions please?

```js
const numbersArray = ['1000','10000','100000']

const splitArrayHandler = (arr) =>{
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let indexOfSymbol = Math.round(arr[i].length / 3)
    return splitAtIndex(arr[i],indexOfSymbol)
  }
}

const splitAtIndex = (value,index) => {
  return value.substring(0,index) + ',' + value.substring(index)
}

splitArrayHandler(numbersArray)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript

Comment: Don't use regex/string parsing for formatting numbers to a certain locale. Javascript has a built-in object for the job.

Comment: Why are you trying to implement what is already built-in? All suggested methods except using `Intl.NumberFormat` will fail e.g. for `9999.99`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are breaking the loop by returning the splitAtIndex function. Create another array and push the results to it.

```
const splitArrayHandler = (arr) =>{
  let arr2 = []
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let indexOfSymbol = Math.round(arr[i].length / 3)
    arr2.push(splitAtIndex(arr[i],indexOfSymbol))
  }
  return arr2
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will accept your answer in 4 minutes

Comment: you are right about `return` un correct usage, though he can overwrite same array and not push to new one

`arr[i] = splitAtIndex(arr[i],indexOfSymbol`

Comment: Don't use regex/string parsing for formatting numbers to a certain locale. Javascript has a built-in object for the job.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) for the job. No need for string parsing / manipulating:

```js
const numbersArray = ['1000', '10000', '100000', '654654686156', '1000.66', '10e14', '0xFFFF'];
const format = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format;

const formattedNumbers = numbersArray.map(Number).map(format);

console.log(formattedNumbers);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use regular expression and `map` function (though there is no real difference between map and hard coded loop)

```
const numbersArray = ['1000','10000','100000']
function addComa(x) {
    return x.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',')
}
const resolved = numbersArray.map(addComma)
console.log(resolved) // ['1,000','10,000','100,000']
```

Comment: I tried that way too but it still only returns single element from list. I need to return all of them

Comment: How well does this work for decimals like `9999.99`?

Comment: As long there is no 4 digits or more after the `.` the code will work as expected. Otherwise add checker in the regex for not being after the `.` or `split` the string at `.`, manipulate `arr[0]`, and `join('.')`